# foursquare api who's been there

Tags: foursquare

I which to display on my website a the list of maybe the last 5 peoples who checked in my venue.
I didn't find any method in the api to do that, the closest was showing your friend...
I tell my boss that it wasn't possible to do that then he shows me this site :

http://www.brooklynmuseum.org/community/foursquare/

How is it possible to get this kind of list and if possible with no authentication (my server will do the call no a real person so no oauth...)

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Venue Push API (documented [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime)) to notify your website whenever a user checks in to your managed venue, which you can use to update such a list.

Comment: Thanks, it is a little bit overkill, I ended up using the venues/stats call to display simply the last 5 users.